# Python Pandas finding column value based on multiple column values in same data frame

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
no  fruit    price  city
1    apple   10     Pune
2    apple   20     Mumbai
3    orange  5      Nagpur
4    orange  7      Delhi
5    Mango   20     Bangalore
6    Mango   15     Chennai
```

Now I want to get city name where "fruit= orange and price =5"

```
df.loc[(df['fruit'] == 'orange') & (df['price'] == 5) , 'city'].iloc[0]
```

is not working and giving error as:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Versions used: Python 3.5

Comment: Looks like your query returns an empty result

Comment: I am able to find result with single condition as df.loc[(df['Fruit'] == 'orange') ].iloc[0]. But getting error when used multiple conditions.

Comment: read my comment above

Comment: basic typo issue `df.loc[(df['fruit'] == 'orange') & (df['price'] == 5) , 'city'].iloc[0]
`

Comment: @Wen: Sorry my typo mistake while posting question. still getting error with this as:

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create masks step-wise and see how they look like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'city': 'Pune', 'fruit': 'apple', 'no': 1L, 'price': 10L},
 {'city': 'Mumbai', 'fruit': 'apple', 'no': 2L, 'price': 20L},
 {'city': 'Nagpur', 'fruit': 'orange', 'no': 3L, 'price': 5L},
 {'city': 'Delhi', 'fruit': 'orange', 'no': 4L, 'price': 7L},
 {'city': 'Bangalore', 'fruit': 'Mango', 'no': 5L, 'price': 20L},
 {'city': 'Chennai', 'fruit': 'Mango', 'no': 6L, 'price': 15L}])

m1 = df['fruit'] == 'orange'
m2 = df['price'] == 5

df[m1&m2]['city'].values[0]  # 'Nagpur'
```

Answer (score 0):

Scalable and programmable solution - utilizes multiIndexing
[Advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-xs)

> 1. Variables
>
>    search_columns=['fruit','price']
>    search_values=['orange','5']
>    target_column='city'
> 2. Make search columns indexes of the df
>
>    df_temp=df.set_index(search_columns)
> 3. Use the 'loc' method to get the value
>
>    value=df_temp.loc[tuple(search_values),target_column]

The result is either a scalar for <=2 search columns or pd.Series
for >2 search columns, respectively

> Snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = "fruit    price  city".split()
data = zip(
    'apple  apple   orange  orange  Mango   Mango'.split(),
    '10 20  5   7   20  15'.split(),
    'Pune   Mumbai  Nagpur  Delhi   Bangalore   Chennai'.split()
)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
search_columns = ['fruit', 'price']
search_values = ['orange', '5']
target_column = 'city'
df_temp = df.set_index(search_columns)
value = df_temp.loc[tuple(search_values), target_column]
print(value)
```

> result: Nagpur